# How to permanently hide NavigationView nav bar in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I believe the recommended way to hide the navigation bar in SwiftUI is as follows (placed on the child of the NavigationView) however when a button is tapped on the view, the view updates itself & the nav bar reappears even though I'm using a constant value of true to hide the bar

```
.navigationBarTitle("")
.navigationBarHidden(true)
.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
```

How do I get the NavigationView's bar to stay hidden on this view?

EDIT

Here is the code for NavigationView, when a gesture/tap happens in a nested subview inside `props.selectedView` the bar appears again

```
NavigationView {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                    ZStack {
                        VStack {
                            props.selectedView
                            Spacer()
                                .frame(height: searchHeaderHeight)
                        }
                        Search()
                    }
                    TabBar()
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: 60)
                        .padding(.bottom, geometry.safeAreaInsets.bottom)
                        .background(Color(.systemGroupedBackground))
                }
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
```

Comment: Would you provide all your code having issue?

Comment: @Asperi I've just updated the question